# Guidelines to write fast code for PyPy's JIT

Tags: python, compilation, jit, pypy, optimization

PyPy's JIT can make Python code execute much faster than CPython. Are there a set of guidelines for writing code that can be optimised better by the JIT compiler? For example, Cython can compile some static code into C++, and it has [guidelines](http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/cythonize.html) to write efficient code. Are there a set of good practices for PyPy? I know that the PyPy project has guidelines for including [hints](http://codespeak.net/pypy/dist/pypy/doc/jit/pyjitpl5.html) while writing your own JIT-enabled interpreters for other dynamic languages, but that is not relevant to most end users of the framework, who are simply using the interpreter. Questions I am wondering about include:

1. Packaging a script into functions
2. Explicitly deleting variables
3. Possible ways of giving, or hinting variable types
4. Writing loops a certain way

Comment: When it comes to JITs, DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) is generally a good guideline.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[PyPy wiki's at BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/wiki/Home) has a section on [JIT Friendliness](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/wiki/JitFriendliness). Some blog posts offer [further advice](http://blog.vrplumber.com/index.php?/archives/2488-PyPy-hits-3x-speed-or-112th,-or-2.5x-depending-on-the-sign-post.html) on making code run fast in PyPy, but AFAIK the idea is that idiomatic code that doesn't force interpreting/realizing frames should be fast and is a bug if it isn't.

I know that for 3, some "assert x > 0" or similar statements can be useful, but I don't remember where I saw that. I also believe I've seen some suggestion about [refactoring conditional-paths-in-loops](http://nighthacks.com/roller/jag/entry/refactoring_considered_harmful_sometimes) related to 4 (edit: this seems to be [outdated](http://www.mail-archive.com/pypy-dev@codespeak.net/msg05478.html) now).

Here's a [thread with some related discussion](http://www.mail-archive.com/pypy-dev@codespeak.net/msg05473.html). You can check how well the JIT is working with your code with [jitviewer](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/jitviewer/src/tip/README), but it's somewhat advanced. Joining #pypy on Freenode will get you help with jitviewer and your particular code.

## 2020+

Since Pypy moved to [Heptapod](https://www.pypy.org/posts/2020/02/pypy-and-cffi-have-moved-to-heptapod-5791595152472747032.html) in 2020, the **JIT Friendliness** has moved here: https://foss.heptapod.net/pypy/pypy/-/wikis/JitFriendliness

Additional performance info is available here: https://www.pypy.org/performance.html