# Writing code for optimizing JIT compiler

Tags: python, compiler-construction, jit, pypy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Guidelines to write fast code for PyPy's JIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318157/guidelines-to-write-fast-code-for-pypys-jit)

I was watching this talk at PyCon: http://pycon.tv/#/video/75

The speakers (the Pypy devs) mentioned that the Python language wasn't the problem with writing a speedy compiler so much as writing your code in a way that helps the JIT do its work quickly.

What are some techniques you can use to help a JIT compiler run quickly? The only one I can think of is that writing your code so it tends to follow the same path over and over again is an obvious help.

Comment: I asked the same question a while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318157/guidelines-to-write-fast-code-for-pypys-jit

It seems there are a few guidelines published with the pypy project. It would be nice if someone could do some benchmarks and compare some approaches on a few problems.